# Как победить ошибку "Unable to find a suitable output format for" в ffmpeg

Tags: python, linux, ffmpeg

Имеется скрипт на python, который генерирует строку параметров для ffmpeg для генерации слайдшоу из картинок. По итогам работы скрипта получается вот такая строка:

```
 -loop 1 -t 3 -i "/home/x/youtube_data/tmp/img010.jpg"
 -loop 1 -t 3 -i "/home/x/youtube_data/tmp/img003.jpg"
 -loop 1 -t 3 -i "/home/x/youtube_data/tmp/img009.jpg"
 -loop 1 -t 3 -i "/home/x/youtube_data/tmp/img019.jpg"
 -filter_complex "[0][1]xfade=transition=circlecrop:duration=0.5:offset=2.5[f0];
                  [f0][2]xfade=transition=circleclose:duration=0.5:offset=5.0[f1];
                  [f1][3]xfade=transition=diagbr:duration=0.5:offset=7.5[f2]"
 -map "[f2]" -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 "/home/x/youtube_data/tmp/video.mp4"
```

В Windows (7 и 10) все работает отлично, а в Xubuntu выдается ошибка

```
[NULL @ 0x562a090906c0] Unable to find a suitable output format for '...вышеуказанная команда...'
 ...вышеуказанная команда...: Invalid argument
```

Запускается команда из скрипта на python:

```
subprocess.run(["ffmpeg ",command])
```

Если остановить скрипт под отладчиком, скопировать полученную команду в буфер обмена и затем просто вставить в консоль:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t....
```

то все работает как надо, видео генерируется без ошибок.
Как побороть данную проблему, ставить Windows ради этого не хочется?

```
x@xvb:~/youtube_data$ 
python3 ./test.py
ffmpeg version 4.4.1-3ubuntu5 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11 (Ubuntu 11.2.0-18ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=3ubuntu5 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
[NULL @ 0x56143bedd6c0] Unable to find a suitable output format for ' -loop 1 -t 3 -i '/home/x/youtube_data/tmp/img010.jpg' -loop 1 -t 3 -i '/home/x/youtube_data/tmp/img003.jpg' -loop 1 -t 3 -i '/home/x/youtube_data/tmp/img009.jpg' -loop 1 -t 3 -i '/home/x/youtube_data/tmp/img019.jpg' -filter_complex '[0][1]xfade=transition=circlecrop:duration=0.5:offset=2.5[f0];                  [f0][2]xfade=transition=circleclose:duration=0.5:offset=5.0[f1];                  [f1][3]xfade=transition=diagbr:duration=0.5:offset=7.5[f2]' -map '[f2]' -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 '/home/x/youtube_data/tmp/video.mp4''
 -loop 1 -t 3 -i '/home/x/youtube_data/tmp/img010.jpg' -loop 1 -t 3 -i '/home/x/youtube_data/tmp/img003.jpg' -loop 1 -t 3 -i '/home/x/youtube_data/tmp/img009.jpg' -loop 1 -t 3 -i '/home/x/youtube_data/tmp/img019.jpg' -filter_complex '[0][1]xfade=transition=circlecrop:duration=0.5:offset=2.5[f0];                  [f0][2]xfade=transition=circleclose:duration=0.5:offset=5.0[f1];                  [f1][3]xfade=transition=diagbr:duration=0.5:offset=7.5[f2]' -map '[f2]' -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 '/home/x/youtube_data/tmp/video.mp4': Invalid argument
```

Comment: Что если фильтры без переносов строк записать? И вообще всю команду в одну строку.

Comment: Так и сделано, я в вопросе просто отформатировал для удобства чтения. А вообще да, все в одну строку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> subprocess.run(["ffmpeg ",command])
> ```

Во-первых, лишний пробел. Во-вторых, каждый параметр должен идти отдельным элементом списка без кавычек, например:

```
subprocess.run(["ffmpeg", "-i", "some file.mp4", "-c", "copy", "out file.mp4"])
```

Comment: Любопытно. Попробую ваш вариант тоже.

Answer (score 0):

Победил проблему.
Вместо

```
subprocess.run(["ffmpeg ",command])
```

надо было запускать

```
subprocess.call("ffmpeg" + command, shell=True)
```

Все работает, всем спасибо. Что это было, я так и не понял... Если кто-то подскажет, в чем была проблема - будет здорово!